# Como alterar dinamicamente os dados do model ao trocar valor da lista que a preenche?

Tags: java, jtable, model

Tenho uma JTable onde tenho uma coluna com o nome de colun1
quero saber como eu faço para alterar os  dados da  JTable quando qualquer dado da lista que  a preenche  for  alterado.
Exemplo

tenho uma lista com nome de listString com 3 valores

```
"String 1"
"String 2"
"String 3"
```

Logo na table apareceriam 3 linhas com os valores acima.

```
// preencher a  table
 public void preencheTable(List<String> listString){
  DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jtable.getModel();
        defaultTableModel.setRowCount(0);
        for (String s : listString) {
            defaultTableModel.addRow(new Object[]{
             s
            });
        }


}
```

Depois  em  algum momento eu resolvo alterar os  valores  da  lista
Ex:

```
//chamo um metodo que adiciona uma nova String na lista que preenche a table.

public void mudarLista(){    
listaString.add("Nova String");
}
```

Qual evento eu tenho que  chamar ou implementar para que na  JTable   o model atualize de  forma  automática.
(Sempre que o conteúdo da  lista  for alterado as  colunas da Jtable também são alteradas).
Neste caso a table teria os  3  valores de  antes mais o valor "Nova String" na quarta  linha.

Comment: Vinicius, você precisa fornecer um **[mcve]**, pois assim poderemos simular seu problema atraves de um código reproduzivel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce tem que *simplesmente* atualizar o `defaultTableModel` que ele irá gerar os eventos necessários para atualizar a JTable.

Uma solução *simples* para automatizar esse procedimento é usar apenas o `DefaultTableModel` para salvar os dados ao invés da List... (gambiarra?)

Provavelmente melhor, mais flexível, principalmente se a aplicação não for muito simples, é criar (extender) uma lista que também implemente o `TableModel`. Aqui um exemplo **muito** simplificado:

```
public class MinhaLista {

    private final List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Modelo modelo = new Modelo();


    public TableModel getTableModel() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public int size() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    public String get(int index) {
        return lista.get(index);
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return lista.contains(o);
    }

    public boolean add(String e) {
        boolean added = lista.add(e);
        if (added) {
            int row = lista.size()-1;
            modelo.fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
        }
        return added;
    }

    public String remove(int index) {
        String removed = lista.remove(index);
        modelo.fireTableRowsDeleted(index, index);
        return removed;
    }

    public void clear() {
        lista.clear();
        modelo.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public MinhaLista() {
    }

    private class Modelo extends AbstractTableModel {

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex != 0)
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("column: " + columnIndex);
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return lista.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            if (column != 0)
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("column: " + column);
            return lista.get(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Usada como em:

```
public class TestMinhaLista {

    private static final MinhaLista lista = new MinhaLista();
    private static final JTextField status = new JTextField();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTable table = new JTable(lista.getTableModel());

        JButton add = new JButton("add");
        add.addActionListener(TestMinhaLista::add);
        JButton remove = new JButton("remove");
        remove.addActionListener(TestMinhaLista::remove);
        JButton clear = new JButton("clear");
        clear.addActionListener(TestMinhaLista::clear);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(add);
        panel.add(remove);
        panel.add(clear);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(status, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.validate();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void add(ActionEvent ev) {
        int num = lista.size() + 1;
        lista.add("linha " + num);
        status.setText("linha " + num + " adicionada");
    }

    private static void remove(ActionEvent ev) {
        if (lista.size() > 0) {
            int index = (int) (Math.random() * lista.size());
            String texto = lista.remove(index);
            status.setText("linha " + (index+1) + " removida: " + texto);
        } else {
            status.setText("nada para apagar");
        }
    }
    private static void clear(ActionEvent ev) {
        lista.clear();
        status.setText("lista serada");
    }
}
```

*(usei delegação em vez de extender a ArrayList, pois prefiro ter que implementar os métodos necessários em vez de ocorrer o risco de esquecer um dos métodos)*